# HTML visible in chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem when writing a html code in chat that appears in the box, this is dangerous and ugly to see, is there any javascript or html code to block html and cone files  ?

if I write on the text input a html code such as  appears in the box ie the code works, how do I block there is a way or some code to paste in the text?

Here is input:

```html
<input type="text" name="chat" id="chattbox" placeholder="Ask what you want." onfocus="placeHolder ()">
```

```
var messages = [], 
  lastUserMessage = "",
  botMessage = "", 
  botName = 'Jacob', t
  talking = true; 

function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "non ho capito";

var hi = ['Ciao {$mybb->user['username']}','mhhh','forte','haha','Chi sei?', 'mi vuoi bene?', 'Sono un bot questo non significa che io sia scemo', 'grande', 'boh', 'bah...', 'sei forte haha', 'ti piace stertix?', 'ok','se lo dici tu.','come vuoi', 'ho fame', 'Mi sto pulendo il naso... Quello che non ho :(', 'Hai ragione', 'Sei un grande', 'aaahhhhhhh!!!', 'mlmlml',  'cavolo', 'wow', 'figo', 'come mai?', 'forse', 'Si', 'No', 'mi piace parlare con te <3', 'spacco bottilia ammazzo familia', 'ti amo', 'ti voglio bene', 'che canzone ti piace?', 'che cantante ti piace?', 'so che pensi che sia stupido ma non lo sono.', 'ma lo sarai tu.', 'va bene', 'bello', 'molto', 'molto bello', 'cosa ne pensi di stertix?', ':D', ':)', ';)', '<3', ':O', 'Che fai?', 'quale?', 'quale', 'eh', 'grave', 'eccellente', 'giusto', 'grazie', 'eccellente', 'ottimo', 'ue guaglio bell stu orolog',];
botMessage = hi[Math.floor(Math.random()*(hi.length))];

var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(gatto|gatti)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {
  botMessage = 'Amo i gatti!';
} 

var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(ciao|salve|ehi|we)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {

var vr = ['Ciao {$mybb->user['username']}!', 'Ciao fra', 'Ciao amico', 'ehi {$mybb->user['username']}!', 'We {$mybb->user['username']}!',];
  botMessage = vr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(vr.length))];

} 


var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(bene)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {
  var vr = ['Ottimo','Meglio cosi', 'Mi fa piacere',];
  botMessage = vr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(vr.length))];
}


var patt = /\b(cani)\b/i;
var result = patt.exec(lastUserMessage);
if (result) {
  botMessage = 'Amo i ' + result[0];
} 

var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(animali)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {
  botMessage = 'Amo gli animali!';
} 

var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(come va|come stai)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {
  var vir = ['Benissimo, tu?','Bene dai...', 'bene tu?', 'male, tu?', 'Malissimo, tu?', 'diciamo, tu?',];
  botMessage = vir[Math.floor(Math.random()*(vir.length))];
} 


var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(che fai|che stai facendo)\b/i);
if (n !== -1) {
  var vuyr = ['Nulla, parlo con te, tu che fai?','Niente, tu?', 'Mi annoio, tu?', 'Mi vedo film zozzi, tu?', 'cerco un modo per conquistare il mondo... na scherzo sono un bot pirla, tu che fai?', ];
  botMessage = vuyr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(vuyr.length))];
}
```

Comment: How do you output the message?

Comment: you can sanitize the input by user

Comment: running in javascript is a chatbot but in the text appears the code that you write html

Comment: Can you show the code for you chatbot? We cannot help you if you don't show us what exactly you are doing.

Comment: If you're using javascript/jquery to output the text, then use `.text(input)` rather than `.html(input)` and then it will output whatever the enter.  If they enter "5 > 3" then you get "5 > 3" - any 'parsing' may remove that ">" and so will not represent what was entered.   Can you provide an example of the sort of text you want removed?

Comment: @Jerodev I updated the post with the code

Comment: @freedomn-m i am using both html and javascript i do not know what to do to block html that is written in the textbox

Comment: @freedomn-m I would like to remove all html codes, you could block these special characters "<>" and "\ /"

Comment: You've not included the *relevant* parts of your code.  ie how you set `lastUserMessage` and where you output `botMessage`.   You can either process it on input or output.  Something like:  `lastUserMessage = lastUserMessage.replace(/\<\>\\\/g, "")`

Comment: @freedomn-m Here is the code lastUserMessage = document.getElementById ("chattbox"). value;

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the code -- basically, if a user enters a < and then, at some point later, types a > then everything between them is stripped out by regex. From what you're describing, this seems like what you're looking for.

```js
var filterHtmlCodes = function() {
  /*****
   * Here, we're going to go through and strip
   *   any tags -- words wrapped in <>. Thus,
   *   users can still enter either symbol, but
   *   entering both will immediately strip the
   *   tag value. I'm triggering on every
   *   keyup, but it could as easily be done on every
   *   change, so as to block copy/paste, for example.
   *****/
  myChatEl.value = myChatEl.value.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')
};

// And I prefer to add my listeners outside of my HTML.
var myChatEl = document.querySelector("#chattbox");
myChatEl.addEventListener("keyup", filterHtmlCodes)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="chat" id="chattbox" placeholder="Ask what you want.">
```

Comment: Every time a key is released, the filterHtmlCodes function triggers. All that code does is take the value of the #chattbox element as a string, and run regex on it to filter out any text surrounded by <...> - so it doesn't actually care if it's an HTML tag or an XML tag or whatever. It assumes that <> denote a tag. Take a look at regex for more. https://javascript.info/regular-expressions